# How to test/debug WP app simulating INDIA culture and language?

Tags: debugging, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Using BugSense I have notice that my app is getting a lot of "NullReferenceExceptions" from country code "IN" (I think it is India). This Exceptions are form different WP7 OS versions, and using different phones (lumia 710, 610, SAMSUNGSGH-i917) - the common factor is IN country code.

Unfortunatelly I don't knows how to test it. In my phone emulator there is no INDIA language.

This Exception also appears on "NOKIARM-820" with Windows8 OS.

questions:

- how to test my app simulating INDIA culture and language?
- how to test my WP7 app on Windows8 phone emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any 'culture' or 'language' based simulation/emulator available.

If you want to test a wp7 app on wp8 run any wp8 emulator(wvga,wxga,720p). But you will face some problems with 720p screen size emulator because wp7 app doesn't scale up with this size.
So, you got to upgrade your app for wp8. Don't worry it's just a click away.

Comment: Thanks aclap.

So you mean that WP7 apps are not compatible with W8? I thought that it is enough to publish WP7 app, and it is automatically available on W8, isn't it? Or it is better to create 2 versions of app - one for WP7 and second for W8?